# Spring Boot not able to use correct schema Postgres - Spring Data + Flyway

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an application that is already running on a working Postgres database.

This database has 3 schemes: console, synchronizer and public, which I use console and synchronizer in my applications.

My application consists of two microservices. One access console schema and another access synchronizer schema, both using spring boot 2.6.6, Spring Data and Flyway.

The apps use the same username and password, they differ only in the connection string.

Application accessing `console`:

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:postgresql://postgres.postgres:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified&currentSchema=console&prepareThreshold=0
```

Application accessing the `synchronizer`:

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:postgresql://postgres.postgres:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified&currentSchema=synchronizer&prepareThreshold=0
```

As I said, it's currently working.

My team is now migrating this database to a high availability Postgres cluster. My DBA did a dump from the working Postgres and restored it into the new Postgres cluster.

Now in this new cluster, my apps are no longer able to use their correct schema. I didn't change anything in the application.properties file. It should work correctly because it's literally a working database dump.

If  `search_path = "$user", public, console, synchronizer`, my application which uses `synchronizer`, ignores its correct schema and tries to use `console`.

If `search_path=console,synchronizer`, again, my application which uses `synchronizer`, ignores its correct schema and tries to use `console`.

If  `search_path = "$user", public` none of the applications will be able to use your scheme. Applications try to create a schema called `"$user", public`.

If  `search_path = synchronizer`, my application using `synchronizer` even manages to access the database, but gives another error: `ERROR: Unable to release PostgreSQL advisory lock`.

What am I missing? There's a configuration that I should apply on the new Postgres?

Application properties `synchronizer-api:`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://postgres.postgres:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified&currentSchema=synchronizer&prepareThreshold=0

spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = password



server.port=8080

...
```

Application properties `console-api:`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://postgres.postgres:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified&currentSchema=console&prepareThreshold=0
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = password



server.port=80

spring.flyway.enabled=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

...
```

Comment: Maybe you added some properties that are overwrting the flyway/jpa schema thats used. Or started with wrong spring-profile because of new deployment config, etc. Could you provide more information in that direction?

Comment: @LenglBoy application.properties added to the question. I didn't changed nothing in the application.properties after migration to new DB. The `synchronizer` application just don't connect to its correct schema  :(